# теряется фокус при переключении раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: windows-10, windows-8

Страшно бесит, что при смене языка (alt + shift) теряется фокус активного окна - будь то работа в MS Office, печатаешь сообщение в скайп, пишешь код в VS, пишешь что-то в браузере, блокноте и т.д. и т.п.. Гуглил эту проблему - но нашел ответы только для linux, Ubuntu и др. операционных системых. Может это проблема именно ноутбуков на windows? Я лично проверял на других ноутбуках(windows) и обнаружил туже проблему, на счет десктопов нечего не могу сказать, так как проверить не на чем.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: [**Mahou**](https://github.com/BladeMight/Mahou) установите, мучения с раскладками должны исчезнуть. Я и забыл, какие клавиши по умолчанию для переключения раскладки используются. // На моём ПК проблема не воспроизводится. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять сочетания клавиш так, чтобы переключать **раскладку клавиатуры**, вместо переключения *языка ввода*.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не понял ответа, но скорее всего вы имели ввиду сменить клавиши для переключения раскладки (с русской на английскую) - не хотелось бы менять горячие клавиши - привык к alt + shift.

Comment: Для каждого языка ввода установите дополнительную клавиатуру (см. первый скриншот). Смену языка ввода на Ctrl+Shift. По Alt-Shift переключайте клавиатуры для выбранного языка (иконка клавы в трее).

Answer (score -1):

Нашел если можно так сказать воркэраунд - нажимать сначала Alt, потом добавлять Shift. Правда всё равно бывают проблемы с зависшей языковой панелью...

Comment: _нажимать сначала Alt, потом добавлять Shift_, и из вопроса _alt + shift_, разве это не одно и тоже?

Comment: если чуть раньше нажать shift то фокус теряется, если alt то нет, по крайней мере у меня так